# Add Video controller in Exoplayer using for Android tv leanback method

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbG6x.png)I cannot able to add the video controller and speed function settings in Exoplayer ,I need the help

need video controller and speed controller menu in simple exoplayer

Answer (score 0):

just read the official documentation, it is enough to implement it:

1. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-new-in-leanback-part-1-a895683c1567
2. https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/transport-controls 
   Also, if it not helps, provide peace of code where you have problem.